# How to have the scrollbar from the second item in the dropdown list

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created scrollbar for the dropdown list elements. I am supposed to start the scrollbar from the second element in the dropdown.

How to achieve that?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2 class="bold">Scrollable Menu</h2>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Scrollable Menu <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
.scrollable-menu {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

estimate or calculate the height up to the second element. then replace it to your height that set into `auto;` then remove the `max-height: 200px;`

```
.scrollable-menu {
    height: estimated height;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```